# Реализация calloc, malloc

Tags: c++

Интересует код возможной реализации функции демонстрирующий причины почему функция malloc принимает один параметр а calloc два?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `calloc` выделяет блок памяти для массива размером — num элементов, каждый из которых занимает  size байт.

Функция `malloc` выделяет блок памяти, размером sizemem байт.